# Grid Gap Boostrap - How to fix?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a grid at bootstrap but when I do not have enough cards  to fill the page they get spaced vertically. I  want them to be grouped with a fix gap between them.

Find image's url attached.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check how to work grid in browser
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/

and use like

```
<div class="container">
  ...
</div>

<div class="row">
  ...
</div>
```